# How to recover a number from digit subsequences?

Tags: algorithm, math

Given the four digit number 1234, there are six possible two digit subsequences (12, 13, 14, 23, 24, 34). Given some of the subsequences, is it possible to recover the original number?

Here's some example data. Each line lists some 3 digit subsequences of a different 6 digit number (to be found)

```
528, 508, 028, 502, 058, 528, 028, 528, 552, 050
163, 635, 635, 130, 163, 633, 130, 330, 635, 135
445, 444, 444, 444, 454, 444, 445, 
011, 350, 601, 651, 601, 511, 511, 360, 601, 351
102, 021, 102, 221, 102, 100, 002, 021, 021, 121
332, 111, 313, 311, 132, 113, 132, 111, 112
362, 650, 230, 172, 120, 165, 372, 202, 702
103, 038, 138, 150, 110, 518, 510, 538, 108
343, 231, 431, 341, 203, 203, 401, 303, 031, 233
```

Edit: Sometimes the solution might not be unique (more than one number could have given the subsequences). In that case, it would be good to return one of them, or maybe even a list.

Comment: What kinda rainbow table is this? ;)

Comment: I don't understand example data. Is there any grouping?

Comment: @Branimir Grouping by rows... I hope. All sequences in the first row are possible subsequences of some unknown 6-digit number.

Comment: If you just need any number with the subsequences, you can simply concatenate all the input numbers. If you need a specific length, you should look at my answer below. If my answer produces a too short solution, you can simply append random numbers till you get one that's long enough. If my answer is too long, it'll be very hard to find the correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let logic programming do the work for you.

This is via [core.logic](https://github.com/clojure/core.logic) in [clojure](/questions/tagged/clojure).

Define what it means to be a subsequence

```
(defne subseqo [s1 s2] 
  ([(h . t1) (h . t2)] (subseqo t1 t2)) 
  ([(h1 . t1) (h2 . t2)] (!= h1 h2) (subseqo s1 t2)) 
  ([() _]))
```

Run the constraints through the solver.

```
(defn recover6 [input-string] 
  (run* [q] 
    (fresh [a b c d e f] 
      (== q [a b c d e f]) 
      (everyg (fn [s] (subseqo (seq s) q)) 
              (re-seq #"\d+" input-string)))))
```

Examples (results are perceptually instantaneous at the REPL):

```
(recover6 "528, 508, 028, 502, 058, 528, 028, 528, 552, 050")
;=> ([\5 \0 \5 \2 \8 \0]
     [\5 \0 \5 \2 \0 \8]
     [\5 \0 \5 \0 \2 \8]
     [\0 \5 \0 \5 \2 \8]
     [\0 \5 \5 \0 \2 \8])

(recover6 "163, 635, 635, 130, 163, 633, 130, 330, 635, 135")
;=> ([\1 \6 \3 \5 \3 \0] 
     [\1 \6 \3 \3 \5 \0] 
     [\1 \6 \3 \3 \0 \5])

(recover6 "445, 444, 444, 444, 454, 444, 445")
;=> ([\4 \4 \5 \4 _0 _1] 
     ... and many more
```

In the last example, the underscores indicate that `_0` and `_1` are free variables. They have not been constrained. It is easy enough to constrain any free variables to the set of digits.

Comment: Given the problem is NP complete, it's probably not ideal to run it through a general purpose solver. Might be very expensive.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is to find the [Shortest common supersequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_common_supersequence) of all your subsequences. Clearly if you have all subsequences, including the original number, the SCS will be what you are looking for. Otherwise it can't be guaranteed, but there's a good chance.

Unfortunately there isn't a nice polynomial algorithm for this problem, but if you Google it you'll find there are a lot of approximation algorithms available. E.g. [An ACO Algorithm for the Shortest Common Supersequene Problem](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.21.4060&rep=rep1&type=pdf) which mentions there are three overall approaches:

1. Dynamic Programming or Branch'n'Bound. These are usually to slow except for very few strings or small alphabets.
2. Finding the SCS of the strings pairwise using Dynamic Programming, using heuristics to choose which strings to 'merge'.
3. The Majority Merge heuristic which might be the nicest one for your case.
4. The approach described in the paper.

Here is another nice article about the problem: http://www.update.uu.se/~shikaree/Westling/

Comment: "will have to be applied pairwise" for test case "111" "222" "121". After first pair you may got "111222", after add third you got "1112221" but it wrong, as for all 3 maybe used "121122".

Comment: Fair enough. It was also for superstrings instead of supersequences. I've linked to a different paper.

Comment: This algo not guarantee correct answer. For string "11121" splitted by 3 sub sequences, you algo may find "11211" (or less size), but in fact string "211" not exist in input data, as result "11211" is not correct answer.

Comment: Yes, but say 11121 is your original number, and it's split into 111, 12 and 21. There is no way for you to know if 11121 or 11211 was the original sequence as either could have generated the subsequences. The SCS is just the most reasonable guess.

Comment: Yes, you are right SCS will be provide a right answer of minimal size.

Answer (score 3):

Build a directed graph with each digit connected to the digit following it in each sequence.

**Dealing with cycles:**

A cycle implies an impossible scenario - a same character cannot have 2 locations (there can be characters with the same values at multiple positions, but not the exact same character - as a metaphor, you can have many people named Bob, but any given Bob can only be at one place). Some node must be split into multiple nodes. The chosen node should be split such that all incoming edges is in one of the new nodes and all outgoing edges is in the other, and there's a connection between the two.

There should be multiple nodes which can be picked to be split, with possibly only one being correct, you may need to explore all possibilities until you find one that works. If one doesn't work, you'll get a longer string than is allowed somewhere down the line.

It might be a better idea to leave getting rid of cycles completely until right before the topological sort (resolving them in the same way).

**Dealing with nodes with the same value (as a result of cycle resolution):**

If there are multiple nodes with the same value that can be chosen, let the outgoing edges go from the first one (the one that has a directed path to all the others) and the incoming edges to the last one (the one which all other ones has a directed path to). This obviously needs to be slightly modified if there are multiple digits with the same value in the same sequence.

**Finding the actual string:**

To determine the string, do a [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) on the graph.

**Example:**

Assume we're looking for a 5-digit number and the input is:

```
528, 508, 028, 502, 058, 058
```

I know the duplication of `058` is somewhat trivial, but it's just for illustration.

For `528`, create nodes for `5`, `2` and `8`, and connect `5` and `2` and `2` and `8`.

```
5 -> 2 -> 8
```

For `508`, create `0`, connect `5` and `0` and `0` and `8`.

```
5 -> 2 -> 8
  \    /
   > 0
```

For `028`, connect `0` and `2`.

```
5 ------> 2 -> 8
  \    /    /
   > 0 -----
```

For `502`, all connections are already there.

For `058`, we get a cycle (`5->0->5`), so we have 2 choices:

- Split `0` into 2 nodes:

  ```
    /-----------\----\
   /             v    v
  0 -> 5 ------> 2 -> 8
         \
          > 0
  ```
- Split `5` into 2 nodes:

  ```
    /-----------\
   /             v
  5 ------> 2 -> 5 -> 8
   \        ^    ^
    \       /    /
     > 0 --------
  ```

Let's assume we go with the latter.

For `058`, we need an outgoing edge from the last `5` (the right `5` in this case) and an incoming edge from the first `5` (the left `5` in this case). These edges (`5->0` and `5->8`) already exists, so there's nothing to do.

A topological sort will give us `50258`, which is our number.

Comment: After 2 choces: you skip answers 05028, 05208, 05280. Which in future insertions maybe required to handle. As in algo used "branching" it is has a hard complexity.

Comment: @Толя I wouldn't recommend it if you're dealing with string that can be hundreds of characters long, but for only 6 characters this should be pretty quick. Well, for 6 characters you can probably just run brute force, but anyway.

Comment: @Толя I believe the possible answers are "50258" "50528" "05028" with the assumed input in this answer. The subsequence "502" is missing from your last two.